# Why I get RuntimeException on AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error while using an AsyncTask. I'm trying get some info from an Excel file using Apache POI. It seems to fail on an Evaluator, used to evaluate cell formulas.
The strange thing is that, when running on the UI thread, it doesn't crash.
Some of the stacktrace is this:

```
2019-01-28 01:55:08.838 9434-9470/skrb.appprueba E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:514)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:278)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:714)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:39)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:179)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:62)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:36)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:514)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:278)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:220)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:200)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:101)
        at reader.ConcreteReader.convertToCustomer(ConcreteReader.java:212)
        at reader.ConcreteReader.readCostumersFromSubFolder(ConcreteReader.java:146)
        at reader.ConcreteReader.readCostumers(ConcreteReader.java:124)
        at reader.ConcreteReader.readCostumersMonth(ConcreteReader.java:79)
        at skrb.appprueba.RouteTask.doInBackground(RouteTask.java:63)
        at skrb.appprueba.RouteTask.doInBackground(RouteTask.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            ... 4 more
```

I'm running this on an OnePlus 6 on Android 9.
My AsyncTask can be found [here](https://github.com/GuidoChia/Venta-de-agua-TDP/blob/MoveAsyncTask/app/src/main/java/skrb/appprueba/RouteTask.java)

> RouteTask.java(AsyncTask)

```
public class RouteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private WeakReference<View> viewReference;

public RouteTask(View view) {
    super();
    viewReference = new WeakReference<>(view);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressBar pb = viewReference.get().findViewById(R.id.progress_recorrido);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
    if (viewReference.get() != null) {
        ProgressBar pb = viewReference.get().findViewById(R.id.progress_recorrido);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Snackbar snackbarAgregado = Snackbar.make(viewReference.get(), R.string.msg_recorrido_creado, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbarAgregado.show();
    }
}

@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... paramams) {
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Date lastMonth = getMonthBefore(today);
    if (lastMonth == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ExcelReader reader = ConcreteReader.getInstance();
    Date[] months = new Date[]{lastMonth, today};
    Collection<Customer> customers = reader.readCostumersMonth(months, 
    fileRW.getPath());
    Collection<Customer> routeCustomers = new 
    ConcreteCustomerManager(customers).getRoute();

    ExcelWriter writer = ConcreteWriter.getInstance();
    writer.WriteRoute(routeCustomers, fileRW.createFileRoute());

    return null;
}

private Date getMonthBefore(Date date) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String dateString = format.format(date);
    String[] strings = dateString.split("/");
    String resString;
    if (Integer.parseInt(strings[1]) == 1) {
        strings[1] = "12";
        int year = Integer.parseInt(strings[2]) - 1;
        strings[2] = String.valueOf(year);
    } else {
        int month = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]) - 1;
        strings[1] = String.valueOf(month);
    }

    resString = strings[0] + '/' + strings[1] + '/' + strings[2];

    try {
        return format.parse(resString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

**EDIT**

Also found that running in a Thread doesn't work either. No clues on what is happening yet.

Comment: opResult = OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(optg, ops, ec); (Apache POI v3.17)

Comment: You should show the entire crash dump - include the "4 more" - the name of the exception that is being fired is missing from your dump.  That's usually the dead giveaway.

Comment: error says that your excl cell formula can't be evaluated

Comment: try this: `Collection<Customer> customers = reader.readCostumersMonth(months, new File(fileRW.getPath()));`

Comment: I'm unable to get this "4 more" as I don't find a way to click them. The thing is that i find really strange that **only** crash while not running on UI Thread.

Comment: from where you are setting value to `fileRW`

Comment: In [fileRW](https://github.com/GuidoChia/Venta-de-agua-TDP/blob/MoveAsyncTask/app/src/main/java/skrb/appprueba/helpers/fileRW.java) the getPath() returns Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), initialized as an static class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally found why this happened. It happens that I was evaluating some formulas on the AsyncTask. This formulas, needed to calculate another formula, and so on. For example, the formula was B41 = B40 + C41*10. Then, B40 = B39 + C40*10, etc. So, this made a big stack of recursive calls, that ended in a stack overflow. This didn't happen (as far as I know) on the UI thread, beacause it has a bigger stack size.